# AirPlay mirroring on iPod touch 4G

Tags: airplay, ios

I've just bought Reflection app for Apple TVize Mac. It works when playing video. Now i've discovered i have also AirPlay Mirroring icon in task bar on my iPod touch (see picture). I've been expecting i'll see screen of my iPod on my Mac. Are there any further steps to do on the iPod to stream the screen?

[image: AirPlayMirroringIcon]

Comment: Do you get the ["Mirroring" toggle switch](http://www.reflectionapp.com/getstarted.php) (shown at the bottom of the page) after pressing the Airplay button and selecting your Mac in the popup as the Airplay target?

Comment: No i don't. Just list of devices to choose from. It seems to be meant just for choosing automatically the sound output source

Comment: The list of Reflector [support devices](http://www.reflectorapp.com/support.php#supportedDevices) suggests that an iPod touch 5th Generation is required for mirroring. Could that be it?

Comment: Maybe, can you please write it as answer, so i can close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an airplay icon, not an airplay mirroring icon on a 4th generation iPod. You need a 5th generation to get mirroring. On the iPad, there is an option for turning mirroring on and off. So on my iPod 4 I get sound but no video on my TV when using Netflix, for instance. On my ipad I get both sound and video.